# Given a section size and a radial angle, make it so that each section is a different color?

Tags: c++, colors, angle

So I have a number of objects inside a circle that I want to color based on its radial angle from the center point. I also would like to be able to pass in the desired section size in angles. So if the section size is 10, then every ten angles would be a different color. So far, I have a way to figure out a color given the angle but, it doesn't really restrict it at all. Essentially, every angle is a different color.

```
R = 256 * Cos(angleValue);    
G = 256 * Cos(angleValue + 120);
B = 256 * Cos(angleValue - 120);
```

I was wondering if anyone would have an idea on how to divide the color wheel into different sections? It would be a bonus but not a requirement if neighboring colors were easily distinguishable. (i.e. red next to blue or something similar)

Or if I am going about this a totally wrong way please feel free to provide any feedback. It would be appreciated.

Comment: It is more natural to use HSV since the hue is an angle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hsv_color_circle.svg

Comment: I can use HSV if necessary. How could I then modify the angle to fit into whichever section it is closest too?

Comment: i = round((angle/360)*N).  hue = i*360/N;  RGB = HSV2RGB(hue, 1, 1);

Comment: Is N the section size in degrees or the number of sections?

Comment: N = number of sections